# How can I place image just left outside visible part of page before animation start?

Tags: css

I want to place my image left outside of page how to do it?

```
         +-------------------+
         | visible page part |
image -> |                   |
         +-------------------+
```

Finally I want to move image inside page.

```
         +-------------------+
         | visible page part |
         | image inside page |
         +-------------------+
```

Comment: any examples of code?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use either negative `margin` or `translateX` transform to achieve this. The below snippet has an example for both approaches.

One thing to note is that the two methods work a bit differently even though their end output is similar. While `translateX(-100%)` moves  element to the left (on the X-axis) by as many pixels as the width of the image, `margin-left: -100%` moves the image by as many pixels as the width of the container of the image. So, if the emphasis is on **just** left outside the visible part then using `translateX(-100%)` is more suitable.

```css
/* using negative margins */

.margin {
  margin-left: -100%;
  animation: marginmove 1s 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes marginmove {
  from {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

/* using translate transforms */

.translate {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: translatemove 2s 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes translatemove {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

/* Just for demo */

body {
  max-width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  padding: 0;
  border: 1px solid;
}
html,
body {
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div>Test content</div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/1" class="margin" />

<div>Test content</div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/100/100/nature/2" class="translate" />
```

> **Note:** As mentioned in comments, if there is a chance that the page's width can become lesser than the viewport's width then it would be imperative to add `overflow: hidden` to the root/parent element (as applicable) to prevent the image from showing up outside the page's left border.

---

You can adapt the above answer to work even when the image is part of a centered column which has equal margins on either sides. Below is a sample snippet to help you:

```css
/* using negative margins */

.margin {
  margin-left: -100%;
  margin-right: 0%;
  animation: marginmove 1s 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes marginmove {
  from {
    margin-left: -100%;
  }
  to {
    margin-left: 0%;
  }
}

/* using translate transforms */

.translate {
  transform: translateX(-100%);
  animation: translatemove 1s 3s forwards;
}
@keyframes translatemove {
  from {
    transform: translateX(-100%);
  }
  to {
    transform: translateX(0%);
  }
}

/* Just for demo */

.container {
  width: 300px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  border: 1px solid;
  overflow: hidden;
}
.container > div{
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/prefixfree/1.0.7/prefixfree.min.js"></script>
<div class='container'>
  <div>Centered column</div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/100/nature/1" class="margin" />
</div>
<div class='container'>
  <div>Centered column</div>
  <img src="http://lorempixel.com/300/100/nature/2" class="translate" />
</div>
```

Comment: It might be helpful for SO to add a note towards `overflow: hidden;` in case the relevant container does not stretch to the viewport limits.

Comment: @connexo: Good point but I didn't add that because OP had mentioned outside visible part of *page*. Then it gets hidden by default :)

Comment: Exactly. Visible part of *page*, not *viewport*. Very few *pages* actually work at `100vw` on large screens; most of them have a fixed `max-width` and `margin: 0 auto;`.

Comment: Ok, so you are referring to the case where the page (or the root element) itself has smaller width? My assumption was page width = viewport width and the use of *container* in your comment put me off a bit (I thought you were referring to a separate container element).

Comment: The root element is always `body`. Most pages have something like `<main>` or `<div id="page">` wrapping their content inside the body.

Comment: Yeah wrong choice of words. I should've explained better. It should have been the root/parent element (root because I have seen pages which do that too :)).

Comment: Problem is only that -100% margin is not bulletproof on large screens but can work is main page column has small margins. I asked little wrong question maybe I should ask again. Inside page there is some centered column with margin.